# Nationality for things

Tags: word-usage

Can we use *nationality* to talk about things? That's OK according to [Random House Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nationality):

> the relationship of property, holdings, etc., to a particular nation, or to one or more of its members: *the nationality of a ship*

But [Collins COBUILD English Usage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nationality) warns against it:

> Be Careful!
>   Don't use 'nationality' to talk about things. Don't say, for example, that something 'has Swedish nationality'. You say that it comes from Sweden or was made in Sweden.
>   *The best vanilla comes from Mexico.*
>   *All of the trucks that Ford sold in Europe were made in Britain.*

How about places? Is it correct to say:

> Q: What nationality is the church in your neighborhood?
>   A: It's a Chinese church.

If not, what's the right question whose answer would be:

> It's a Chinese church.

Comment: I have never heard _Chinese church_. You say it's a Catholic church, or a Protestant church.

Comment: I would expect _It's is a Buddhist church frequented mostly by local Chinese residents. It's an Orthodox Church with a large Ethiopian congregation._

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Here's the [source](http://police.digitaler.net/pdf/exam/103-21.pdf).

Comment: @mplungjan: How about a Chinese restaurant, or an Armenian flower shop?

Comment: Then the restaurant is serving Chinese food and/or owned by people of Chinese nationality. There are no Chinese churches I know of. There are Russian Orthodox and Ukrainian Orthodox churches, but I have not heard them (officially) mentioned as the _Russian Church_ or _Ukrainian Church_ but you can of course understand what is meant when it is used that way.

Comment: @Mori Although it's not phrased as the *nationality* of a church, one can speak of a church's primary *ethnicity*. So a church whose congregation is mostly African might be called an African church, and one with mostly Chinese may be called a Chinese church. One might also speak of a Chinese or English  service to specify the language used in the service.

Comment: @Lawrence: So is it OK to ask "What _ethnicity_ is the church in your neighborhood?"? If not, what's the right question whose answer would be "It's a Chinese church."?

Comment: @Mori Yes, I would treat such a question as asking about the ethnicity of the majority of the people attending that church. It's an example of [metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy), like saying *the class is having an excursion* when trying to express that the *students* of that class are having an excursion.

Comment: This American English speaker sees absolutely nothing wrong with "Chinese church".  In fact, [there are a bunch of places in my hometown which have names very similar to that.](https://www.google.com/maps/search/chinese+church/@40.7281679,-74.0619115,13z/data=!3m1!4b1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ships you mentioned are a special case - and this has really nothing to do with the English language, but with international law. A ship is officially registered in some country, and that is its nationality, and it has significant legal meaning.

An embassy or consulate might have a nationality.

Comment: Am embassy has its nationality since, for example, the American embassy in a country is American territory.

Answer (score 0):

Substantially there is no grammaticall error to put any adjective or nationality before men or things as the modifier as far as the neaning is acceptable for example a persian cat or a Persian rug.

Comment: The OP is asking if it is correct to talk of _nationality of a church_ in the same way it is done with _nationality of a ship_.